# How to change number last digit

Tags: php

Change price to always show as: 29, 39, 49, 59, 69, 79, 89 or 99.
 
Eg: if price is 2018 = 2029
Or if price is 1051 then markup to: 1059

Comment: So you want the number to always end in 9?

Comment: Why would 2018 go to 2029 and not 2019?

Comment: `round($num, - 1) - 1;` lol

Comment: price fix display more then or equal 29 last digit.

Comment: So, have you tried anything yourself already?

Comment: $num = 2533; echo round($num, - 1) - 1; return 2529 but i want this 2339.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of floating number, it won't work.

You first need to check whether value is integer (decimal) or float.
And after that, you need to process logic accordingly.

make a function like below:

```
function addVal($price){
    $price = 10.50;
    if(is_float($price)){
        $whole = floor($price);      // 1
        $fraction = $n - $whole;
        $final = getVal($whole,$fraction);
    }else{
        $final = getVal($price);
    }
    return $final;
}
function getVal($price,$fraction=0){
    // your logic goes here
    if($fraction!=0){
        // add fractional part to price after applying logic
    }
    return $price;
}
```

Regards

Comment: It works with nominal changes! Thanks!

Comment: by the way, $n will be replaced by $price. please note that

Answer (score 4):

Seems simple enough. Separate the number into two parts (pseudo-code below):

```
remainder = number % 100           # gives 0 thru 99 inclusive
hundreds = number - remainder      # give x00, where x is any sequence of digits.
```

Then adjust the remainder with something like:

```
if      remainder <= 29:  remainder = 29
else if remainder <= 39:  remainder = 39
else if remainder <= 49:  remainder = 49
else if remainder <= 59:  remainder = 59
else if remainder <= 69:  remainder = 69
else if remainder <= 79:  remainder = 79
else if remainder <= 89:  remainder = 89
else:                     remainder = 99
```

Then recombine them:

```
number = hundreds + remainder
```

You could simplify the middle bit into an expression if you so desire but, depending on the business logic, it may be better off leaving as-is, in case the boundaries become `.29`, `.37`, `.53` (or anything not immediately amenable to a formula).

---

By way of example, here's some Python code (the ultimate pseudo-code language) which does what you want:

```
def adjust (n):
    r = n % 100
    n = n - r

    if   r <= 29:  r = 29
    elif r <= 39:  r = 39
    elif r <= 49:  r = 49
    elif r <= 59:  r = 59
    elif r <= 69:  r = 69
    elif r <= 79:  r = 79
    elif r <= 89:  r = 89
    else:          r = 99

    return n + r


print "%4d -> %4d\n" % (1562, adjust(1562))
for i in range (89,190):
    print "%3d -> %3d" % (i, adjust(i))
```

The output is as expected:

```
1562 -> 1569

 89 ->  89
 90 ->  99
 91 ->  99
 92 ->  99
 93 ->  99
 94 ->  99
 95 ->  99
 96 ->  99
 97 ->  99
 98 ->  99
 99 ->  99
100 -> 129
101 -> 129
102 -> 129
103 -> 129
104 -> 129
105 -> 129
106 -> 129
107 -> 129
108 -> 129
109 -> 129
110 -> 129
111 -> 129
112 -> 129
113 -> 129
114 -> 129
115 -> 129
116 -> 129
117 -> 129
118 -> 129
119 -> 129
120 -> 129
121 -> 129
122 -> 129
123 -> 129
124 -> 129
125 -> 129
126 -> 129
127 -> 129
128 -> 129
129 -> 129
130 -> 139
131 -> 139
132 -> 139
133 -> 139
134 -> 139
135 -> 139
136 -> 139
137 -> 139
138 -> 139
139 -> 139
140 -> 149
141 -> 149
142 -> 149
143 -> 149
144 -> 149
145 -> 149
146 -> 149
147 -> 149
148 -> 149
149 -> 149
150 -> 159
151 -> 159
152 -> 159
153 -> 159
154 -> 159
155 -> 159
156 -> 159
157 -> 159
158 -> 159
159 -> 159
160 -> 169
161 -> 169
162 -> 169
163 -> 169
164 -> 169
165 -> 169
166 -> 169
167 -> 169
168 -> 169
169 -> 169
170 -> 179
171 -> 179
172 -> 179
173 -> 179
174 -> 179
175 -> 179
176 -> 179
177 -> 179
178 -> 179
179 -> 179
180 -> 189
181 -> 189
182 -> 189
183 -> 189
184 -> 189
185 -> 189
186 -> 189
187 -> 189
188 -> 189
189 -> 189
```

Comment: this is not working properly. When i am number input 1562 it's return 6299.

Comment: @user3223673: I suugest you try to implement the code _again._ With `1562` as input, `remainder` gets set to `62` and `hundreds` becomes `1500`. The `remainder` should then be upgraded to `69` and recombined to give `1569` (as per my sample code). If it doesn't, your problem lies with the translation om my pseudo-code to your language of choice.

Comment: Another twist in comments, now decimal values are also in the picture: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25008485/how-to-change-number-last-digit/25008553?noredirect=1#comment38886868_25008774

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
if (substr($price, -2) >= 20) {
    $price = substr($price, 0, -1) . 9;
} 
else {
    $price = substr($price, 0, -2) . 29; 
}
```

[**see demo** *Updated with multiple examples*](http://codepad.org/5IPPXM31)

---

*Update with suggestion from @HankyPanky in comments. For more simplicity, use the ternary operator:*

```
$price = substr($price,-2) >= 20 ? substr($price,0,-1) . 9 : substr($price,0,-2) . 29;
```

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky That's what I thought at first but re-read the OPs question and his comment (#4). Any number less than x29 should be rounded to 29. Note the wording of the question: `Change price to always show as: 29, 39, 49, 59, 69, 79, 89 or 99`. It does not include 09 or 19.

Comment: Mark may I suggest adding this option to your neat answer. `$price=substr($price, -2) >= 20 ? substr($price, 0, -1) . 9 : substr($price, 0, -2) . 29;`

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Yes that's a great suggestion. I have added your input to the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

need to compare last 2 values using substr function as shown above. then check condition for nearest possible values. 
there you go. DONE .

```
if (substr($price, -2) <= 29) {
    $price = substr($price, 0, -2) . 29;
} 
else if  (substr($price, -2) <=39) {
    $price = substr($price, 0, -2) . 39; 
}
```

AND  SO ON....

CHEERS...

Comment: The 'and so on' is not necessary. There is no need for a long list else if statements. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25008485/how-to-change-number-last-digit/25008563#25008563) for a simpler way to do this.

Comment: Now there is another twist. What about the decimal values ? :) They just mentioned http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25008485/how-to-change-number-last-digit/25008553?noredirect=1#comment38886868_25008774

Comment: when $variable price 3635.50 will it be 3639.9 ? @HK_Khunt

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by making your php function with the use of round function of PHP

Answer (score 0):

It is working fully. I have tested in my local server.

```
<?php
 $variable=1255;
 $len=strlen ( $variable );
 $last_2nd=substr($variable,$len-2,1);
 if ($last_2nd==1)
 $last_2nd=2;
 $last=substr($variable,$len-1,1);
 $last=$last+(9-$last);
 $variable=substr($variable,0,$len-2).$last_2nd.$last;
 echo $variable;
?>
```

Comment: Hello when $variable price 3635.50 it's return 3635.9 but i want this 3639.9

Comment: That's another complicated job. But have to sole in this way as I calculated. Do you know programming? @HK_Khunt . Thanks for testing my answer.

Comment: If $variable price 3635.57 what will be your answer? @HK_Khunt